# Trying to reference a query in a c# class

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I'm trying to accomplish 2 things with the below snippet of code (from ApplicationDataService.lsml.cs in the server project of my Lightswitch 2013 solution).

```
partial void Query1_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<CandidateBasic> query)
{
    query = from item in query where item.CreatedBy == this.Application.User.Name select item;
}

partial void CandidateBasics_Validate(CandidateBasic entity, EntitySetValidationResultsBuilder results)
{
    var newcandidateCount = this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Details.GetChanges().AddedEntities.OfType<CandidateBasic>().Count();
    var databasecandidateCount = this.CandidateBasics.GetQuery().Execute().Count();

    const int maxcandidateCount = 1;

    if (newcandidateCount + databasecandidateCount > maxcandidateCount)
    {
        results.AddEntityError("Error: you are only allowed to have one candidate record");
    }
}
```

Firstly, I want to make sure each user can only see things that he has made. This, together with a preprocess query on the table in question, works perfectly.

The next bit is designed to make sure that each user can only create one record in a certain table. Unfortunately, it seems to be looking at the whole table, and not the query I made that shows only the user's own records.

How can I get that second bit of code to limit only the user's own records, and not the global table?

Comment: this seems like something that should be enforced SQL-side with a primary key or unique constraint

Comment: I don't know Lightswitch, but are you saying that you want to conditionally exclude the `PreprocessQuery` in certain contexts (e.g. `databasecandidateCount`) but to apply it in others (restrict user to only items created by him)?

Comment: No, I'd like the `PreprocessQuery` to be applied to the `databasecandidateCount`, so that it's a count of the records the query returns, rather than a count of the records in the table. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually calling that query though are you? Your query is called Query1 based on the code provided yet you don't seem to be calling it. I'd do something like:

```
int count = DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Query1().Count();
```